# OLA Output File Cleanup - Better Options

Tags: sql-server-agent, jobs, maintenance, ola-hallengren

Does anyone have a way to change the Ola Hallengren "Output File Cleanup" job that doesn't require CmdExec? My company is trying to eliminate CmdExec where ever possible. I was thinking a PowerShell script may work but I really don't know where to start. Any help, even just a simple point in the right direction, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Removing Old SQL Server backup files with PowerShell](https://stuart-moore.com/removing-old-sql-server-backup-files-powershell/)